# UnsatisfiedLinkError with sqlite4java Jar on Mac OS X NetBeans

Tags: java, macos, sqlite, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am getting experiencing a similar problem to this question:

[UnsatisfiedLinkError with sqlite4java Jar on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301562/unsatisfiedlinkerror-with-sqlite4java-jar-on-mac-os-x)

However, I am running on a Mac, and I have the relevant libraries in my lib folder.  However, if I run this as is I get the UnsatisfiedLinkError. If I run "java -jar sqlite4java.jar -d" I get the following output:

```
sqlite4java 282
130321:222850.424 FINE [sqlite] Internal: loading library
130321:222850.425 FINE [sqlite] Internal: java.library.path=/Users/mikey/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
130321:222850.425 FINE [sqlite] Internal: sqlite4java.library.path=null
130321:222850.425 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cwd=/Users/mikey/NetBeansProjects/Test/lib/.
130321:222850.425 FINE [sqlite] Internal: default path=/Users/mikey/NetBeansProjects/Test/lib
130321:222850.425 FINE [sqlite] Internal: forced path=null 
130321:222850.426 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.name=mac os x; os=osx
130321:222850.426 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.arch=x86_64
130321:222850.426 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-x86_64
130321:222850.427 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-x86_64: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path
130321:222850.427 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-amd64
130321:222850.428 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-amd64: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-amd64 in java.library.path
130321:222850.428 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-10.4
130321:222850.431 INFO [sqlite] Internal: loaded sqlite4java-osx-10.4 from system path
130321:222850.433 INFO [sqlite] Internal: loaded sqlite 3.7.10, wrapper 0.2
SQLite 3.7.10
Compile-time options: ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA ENABLE_FTS3 ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS ENABLE_LOCKING_STYLE=0 ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT ENABLE_RTREE OMIT_DEPRECATED TEMP_STORE=1 THREADSAFE=1
```

I can see that it is looking for the sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 library, so I then ran both "ln -s libsqlite4java-osx.jnilib libsqlite4java-osx-x86_64.jnilib" and "ln -s libsqlite4java-osx-10.4.jnilib libsqlite4java-osx-x86_64.jnilib" and that seems to help:

```
sqlite4java 282
130321:223211.473 FINE [sqlite] Internal: loading library
130321:223211.474 FINE [sqlite] Internal: java.library.path=/Users/mikey/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
130321:223211.474 FINE [sqlite] Internal: sqlite4java.library.path=null
130321:223211.474 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cwd=/Users/mikey/NetBeansProjects/Test/lib/.
130321:223211.474 FINE [sqlite] Internal: default path=/Users/mikey/NetBeansProjects/Test/lib
130321:223211.474 FINE [sqlite] Internal: forced path=null 
130321:223211.475 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.name=mac os x; os=osx
130321:223211.475 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.arch=x86_64
130321:223211.475 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-x86_64
130321:223211.477 INFO [sqlite] Internal: loaded sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 from system path
130321:223211.479 INFO [sqlite] Internal: loaded sqlite 3.7.10, wrapper 0.2
SQLite 3.7.10
Compile-time options: ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA ENABLE_FTS3 ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT ENABLE_RTREE OMIT_DEPRECATED TEMP_STORE=1 THREADSAFE=1
```

Seems fine, right?  No.  When I try and run my java code, it fails yet again when trying to open the database with the UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Is there something obvious I am missing?  Here is an ls of the relevant part my lib directory just as a sanity check:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikey  staff   466792  1 Mar  2012 libsqlite4java-android-armv7.so
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikey  staff   790986  1 Mar  2012 libsqlite4java-linux-amd64.so
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikey  staff   732637  1 Mar  2012 libsqlite4java-linux-i386.so
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikey  staff  1400368  1 Mar  2012 libsqlite4java-osx-10.4.jnilib
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikey  staff  1401592  1 Mar  2012 libsqlite4java-osx-ppc.jnilib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 mikey  staff       25 21 Mar 22:31 libsqlite4java-osx-x86_64.jnilib -> libsqlite4java-osx.jnilib
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikey  staff  1433640  1 Mar  2012 libsqlite4java-osx.jnilib
-rw-r--r--   1 mikey  staff      928 17 Mar 17:05 nblibraries.properties
drwxr-xr-x   3 mikey  staff      102 15 Mar 18:59 sqlite4java
drwxr-xr-x  13 mikey  staff      442 19 Mar 17:49 sqlite4java-282 2
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikey  staff   102236  1 Mar  2012 sqlite4java-docs.zip
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikey  staff   100502  1 Mar  2012 sqlite4java-src.zip
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikey  staff   622080  1 Mar  2012 sqlite4java-win32-x64.dll
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikey  staff   462848  1 Mar  2012 sqlite4java-win32-x86.dll
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikey  staff   129381  1 Mar  2012 sqlite4java.jar
```

And a copy of my database connection code:

```
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection;
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Wrapper for Sqlite
 *
 * @author mikey
 */
public class Database {

    private SQLiteConnection db;

    public Database() {
        db = new SQLiteConnection(new File("./test.db"));
        try {
            db.open(true);
        } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any light you can shed on my problem...

**EDIT**

In response to @sereda here is the output from putting "com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.main(new String[] {"-d"});" into the database connection code:

```
sqlite4java 282
130322:161109.097 FINE [sqlite] Internal: loading library
130322:161109.099 FINE [sqlite] Internal: java.library.path=/Users/mikey/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
130322:161109.100 FINE [sqlite] Internal: sqlite4java.library.path=null
130322:161109.100 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cwd=/Users/mikey/NetBeansProjects/Test/.
130322:161109.101 FINE [sqlite] Internal: default path=/Users/mikey/NetBeansProjects/Test/lib
130322:161109.101 FINE [sqlite] Internal: forced path=null 
130322:161109.102 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.name=mac os x; os=osx
130322:161109.102 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.arch=x86_64
130322:161109.105 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-x86_64
130322:161109.108 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-x86_64: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path
130322:161109.108 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-amd64
130322:161109.112 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-amd64: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-amd64 in java.library.path
130322:161109.112 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-10.4
130322:161109.115 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-10.4: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-10.4 in java.library.path
130322:161109.115 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx
130322:161109.118 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx in java.library.path
130322:161109.119 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java
130322:161109.122 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java in java.library.path
130322:161109.123 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-x86_64-d
130322:161109.127 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-x86_64-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64-d in java.library.path
130322:161109.127 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-amd64-d
130322:161109.131 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-amd64-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-amd64-d in java.library.path
130322:161109.131 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-10.4-d
130322:161109.134 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-10.4-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-10.4-d in java.library.path
130322:161109.134 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-d
130322:161109.137 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-d in java.library.path
130322:161109.138 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-d
130322:161109.141 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-d in java.library.path
Error: cannot load SQLite
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromSystemPath(Internal.java:349)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:124)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.main(SQLite.java:368)
    at frakdeck.Database.<init>(Database.java:19)
    at frakdeck.Test.start(Test.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
```

Comment: You can see this play out in this other Stack Overflow answer, which also covers how to programatically set `java.library.path` if needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35353377/3679676

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution of :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException:
[-91]cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64
in java.library.path
```

Please try running this:

```
 java -jar sqlite4java.jar -d
```

to make it try to load all variants of the binary and verify the results.

the result must be like this:

```
java -jar sqlite4java.jar -d
sqlite4java 282
121212:134119.239 FINE [sqlite] Internal: loading library
121212:134119.239 FINE [sqlite] Internal:java.library.path=/Users/XXXXX/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
121212:134119.240 FINE [sqlite] Internal: sqlite4java.library.path=null
121212:134119.240 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cwd=XXXXX
121212:134119.240 FINE [sqlite] Internal: default path=XXXXX
121212:134119.240 FINE [sqlite] Internal: forced path=null 
121212:134119.240 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.name=mac os x; os=osx
121212:134119.240 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.arch=x86_64
121212:134119.240 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-x86_64
121212:134119.243 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-x86_64: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path
121212:134119.243 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-amd64
121212:134119.244 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-amd64:         java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-amd64 in java.library.path
121212:134119.244 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-10.4
121212:134119.249 INFO [sqlite] Internal: loaded sqlite4java-osx-10.4 from system path
121212:134119.252 INFO [sqlite] Internal: loaded sqlite 3.7.10, wrapper 0.2
SQLite 3.7.10
Compile-time options: ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA ENABLE_FTS3 ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS     ENABLE_LOCKING_STYLE=0 ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT ENABLE_RTREE OMIT_DEPRECATED TEMP_STORE=1    THREADSAFE=1
```

The files are tried in the order of more specific to less specific. So the order is correct.

The problem is that there's no more specific binary -so we might need to rename ***libsqlite4java-osx.jnilib*** to ***libsqlite4java-osx-amd64.dylib***.

Comment: I already have output like that on the command line, I have included it in my question, it is when I try and use the library in my code in NetBeans that I see the error

Comment: you have to rename libsqlite4java-osx.jnilib to libsqlite4java-osx-amd64.dylib (for Mac OSX)

Comment: Oh, I see now, this also works as a solution - sorry for not seeing what you wrote correctly

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error for my program after upgrade to Mountain Lion. When I added the libraries to 
/Libraries/Java/Extensions
he program run fine. I don't know if this the best solution, but it worked.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me on Eclipse. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed your answer when you answered. It does work, but looking into the output has led me to an idea as to what is going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is the problem, but you can try running sqlite4java's diagnostics code from within your program and see if it shows the same loading sequence:

```
public Database() {
    com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.main(new String[] {"-d"});
    db = new SQLiteConnection(new File("./test.db"));
    ...
```

Comment: I have added the code above and can see that it is not finding any of the libraries - I can them them there so I really do not know how to proceed...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but managed to get it to load sqlite by creating the libs folder from the IDE and then copying the jar into the new libs folder.  Then I removed the old version of the jar from the build path and added in the new one.  Hope this helps!