# UnsatisfiedLinkError with sqlite4java, no sqlite4java-osx-amd64

Tags: java, sqlite

I am having a similar issue to this problem:

[UnsatisfiedLinkError with sqlite4java Jar on Mac OS X NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559551/unsatisfiedlinkerror-with-sqlite4java-jar-on-mac-os-x-netbeans)

I am running a script that uses sqlite, and while I am able to successfully run sqlite3 through the command line, I always get this error when I try to run the script:

```
SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[master.catalog]: error running job queue
com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-amd64 in java.library.path
```

When I run "java -jar sqlite4java.jar -d" in my lib folder, I see this:

```
140428:170139.831 FINE [sqlite] Internal: loading library
140428:170139.853 FINE [sqlite] Internal: java.library.path=/Users/lee33/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
140428:170139.853 FINE [sqlite] Internal: sqlite4java.library.path=null
140428:170139.853 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cwd=/Users/lee33/Desktop/myria_workspace/myria/lib/sqlite4java-282/.
140428:170139.853 FINE [sqlite] Internal: default path=null 
140428:170139.853 FINE [sqlite] Internal: forced path=null 
140428:170139.854 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.name=mac os x; os=osx
140428:170139.854 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.arch=amd64
140428:170139.854 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-amd64
140428:170139.855 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-amd64: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-amd64 in java.library.path
140428:170139.855 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-10.4
140428:170139.856 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-10.4: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-10.4 in java.library.path
140428:170139.856 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx
140428:170139.857 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx in java.library.path
140428:170139.857 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java
140428:170139.858 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java in java.library.path
140428:170139.858 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-amd64-d
140428:170139.859 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-amd64-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-amd64-d in java.library.path
140428:170139.859 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-10.4-d
140428:170139.859 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-10.4-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-10.4-d in java.library.path
140428:170139.860 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-osx-d
140428:170139.860 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-osx-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-d in java.library.path
140428:170139.860 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-d
140428:170139.861 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-d in java.library.path
Error: cannot load SQLite
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-amd64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromSystemPath(Internal.java:349)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:124)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.main(SQLite.java:368)
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am missing?

Comment: Have you actually checked that the library is on the `java.library.path`?

Comment: This post point in the right direction https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlite4java/O8u1h5CSVTE/-1aKaTOs_M8J

Comment: After I updated the dependencies in the Projects build.gradle it worked again. I don't know what in detail it fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `java.library.path` does not include the current directory.

The default on my OSX box is:

```
/Users/MY_USERNAME/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
```

But yours reads

```
/Users/MY_USERNAME/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
```

Note the `:.` at the end of the first line.

You should be able to get it to work by either running

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -jar sqlite4java.jar
```

Or by copying `*.jnilib` files from `sqlite4java-282.zip` into any directory in `java.library.path` (e.g. `/Users/lee33/Library/Java/Extensions`)

Or by adjusting the path for the project in an IDE of your choice:

- [How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse)
- [giving 'java.library.path' in netbeans for .dll/.so files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714785/giving-java-library-path-in-netbeans-for-dll-so-files/11898261)

See also:

- [Default Java library path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038789/default-java-library-path)

Comment: I appreciate the answer, unfortunately none of these methods worked for me, I must be having some obscure issue that isn't obvious.  Thanks for the answer though, I am sure it will help others!

Comment: I ended up copying the entire sqlite4java-282 folder to /Users/MY_USERNAME/Library/Java/Extensions (which didn't exist anymore for some reason so I remade it) and this worked, so thank you for the help, lot of good info here.