# Database tests failing Robolectric 2.4 + Ubuntu 14 + GradleWrapper 2.4

Tags: android, unit-testing, ubuntu, robolectric

We have some robolectric tests that use sqlite4java. 
These tests pass on MAC OS but fail on Ubuntu with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at <classname>  
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at <classname>  
Caused by: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException at <classname>
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError at <classname>
```

The java.library.path is: java.library.path=.:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib

We referred to this: [UnsatisfiedLinkError with sqlite4java Jar on Mac OS X NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559551/unsatisfiedlinkerror-with-sqlite4java-jar-on-mac-os-x-netbeans) but on renaming, the build tools created a new .so file.

We also referred this https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/958 but it seems that they have fixed the issue in robolectric 2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant /tmp executable rights:

> sudo mount -o remount, exec /tmp